# Ajax / PHP : pass variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I'm passing the two variables to my php I get `Notice: Undefined index : name` & `Notice: Undefined index : parsed`.

When I'm adding an `echo` for each variable, I get nothing.

Nothing is added in my database.

```
name = "myName";
parsed = someCode.toJSON();

parsed = JSON.stringify(parsed, null, '\t');
parsed = parsed.replace(/[\n\t]+([\d\.e\-\[\]]+)/g, '$1');

$.ajax({
    url: 'js/function/scriptSave.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {name : name, parsed : parsed},
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(err){ 
        alert('Error'+err);
    }
});
```

The Ajax always returns me the error case : `Error [object Object]`

When I'm replacing my variables with text, everything works:

```
data: {name : 'name', parsed : 'parsed'}
```

And when I remove the json variable only it works.
I really don't understand what happens here..

**[EDIT]**

The variable containing the name is ok. But when I only put the variable containing the json, it doesn't work. But what is the problem with this variable ?

So far, I have tried:

```
    var obj = {}; obj.name = 'myName'; obj.parsed = someCode.toJSON();
    {data : JSON.stringify(obj)}
///////
    {'name' : name, 'parsed' : parsed}
///////
    {parsed : JSON.stringify(parsed)}
```

Here's my php:

```
<?php
if (!@mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pwd')) {
    die("Error");
} else {
    mysql_select_db('database');
}

    $parsed = $_POST["parsed"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO object(name, parsed) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$parsed."')");
?>
```

**[EDIT 2]**

When I'm changing dataType from `JSON` to `TEXT` the ajax is in success case, but nothing is inserted in DB...

When I'm looking in my devTools in chrome everything semm to be ok :

**General**

```
Request Method :POST
Status Code: 200 OK
```

**Response Headers**

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

**Request Headers**

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

**Form Data**

```
name : myName
parsed : {"another" : "value"}
```

**[EDIT 3]**

The problem seems to come from the json size... When I'm excluding some fields, everything seems to work. The problem is that in my databse, my field which will contain my JSON, is a LongText... The JSON size doesn't have to be the problem..

Comment: and what name and parsed should be??

Comment: name is a simple text and parsed is a parsed json code

Comment: Ok but where you defined them in your code??

Comment: Ok try to pass each value individually like {name : name}

Comment: It only works with `name` but not with the variable containing the json

Comment: good .. so try to use {parsed : JSON.stringify(parsed)}

Comment: I added `parsed = JSON.stringify(parsed)` and nothng changed :/

Comment: look at this  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.85).aspx  .. I don't know about dataType:'JSON' and dataType : 'json' .. I don't know its same or not but I always see it in a lowercase

Comment: JSON or json is the same :s

Comment: Thanks about that :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96273/discussion-between-srcbh-and-mohamed-yousef).

Comment: try to put them in object `var obj = {}; obj.name = 'myName' obj.parsed = someCode.toJSON()` and sent just the object. `data: obj`

Comment: try using {'name' : name, 'parsed' : parsed} instead of {name : name, parsed : parsed}

Comment: Let's see the PHP as well.

Comment: please show your php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj` should be send as string, when calling the Ajax `POST` method.

So, combine the `data` into one `Object` and stringify it with `JSON.stringify()` method.

```
var obj = {};
obj.name = "your name";
obj.parsed = { "another" : "value" };

$.ajax({
    url: 'js/function/scriptSave.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(err){ 
        alert('Error'+err);
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. same situation as before.. :/

Comment: Just console log the `obj` before calling `$.ajax` and inside of the `success` and `error` callbacks. Let us know, what specific problem you are facing.

Comment: `console.log()` 's are returning me :
`sceneName : "your name" ////
sceneParsed :  Object { another="value"} ////
    another "value"` It gets in the error case.. and nothing is inserted in database..

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the **JSON.stringify()**.